# Can't connect to Postgres in read-write mode

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am using psql to connect to database.

I can connect in `read-only` mode (`target_session_attrs` param has default value),
but when I try to connect in `read-write` mode (`target_session_attrs` param has `read-write` value) I get following message:

`psql: could not make a writable connection to server 'server_name'`

1. What can be the reason of this error?
2. How can I connect to db using psql in `read-write` mode?

Comment: Because your connect string didn't contain a server where you can write.

Comment: What is the setting for [default_transaction_read_only](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/runtime-config-client.html)?

Comment: Laurenz, could you please give some reference to read or clarify your answer. I don't quite understand what is server in connection string and I don't see something like that in documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html. You don't mean host, do you, which was localhost in my case?